# Simple Sass BEM inheritance for modifiers

Tags: sass, bem

I know this seems like a basic question, but despite all the great writings about sass and bem I'm missing how this inheritance works with nesting. Maybe someone here can clarify.

For example, a simple nav with links and active links:

```
.Header {
    padding: 1rem;


    &__nav {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;

        &-link {
            @include fonts.bold;
            font-size: 1.15rem;

            &--active {
                color: red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then this component:

```
const NavLink = props => (
    <Link
        {...props}
        getProps={({ isCurrent }) => ({
            className: isCurrent ? "Header__nav-link--active" : "Header__nav-link",
        })}
    />
);

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <header className="Header">
            <div className="Header__nav">
                <NavLink to="/app/A">PAGE A</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/app/B">PAGE B</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/app/C">PAGE C</NavLink>
            </div>
        </header>
    );
};
```

#### PROBLEM

Links that are not active - `Header__nav-link` get the font settings but the `--active` link does not. Is the "correct" way to do this by adding the base class to the markup along with `active`?

Like this: `className="Header__nav-link Header__nav-link--active"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the correct way is what you described. Modifiers in BEM are intended to be used with a block class to alter it in some way from the base. If you think about it, a modifier class cannot be by itself because it has no defined block to modify.

Comment: That makes sense. Was just thinking that the inheritance could "absorb" all of the downstream properties, but in hindsight, that doesn't make a lot of sense. Thank you!